# Why is there no 'powershell' tab in the group policy scripts dialog?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, powershell

I would like to run a powershell script at startup but there is no 'powershell' tab on the dialog box.

I am running Windows Server 2008 64-bit.

Thanks!

Comment: what's your functional level?

Comment: Windows Server 2008

Comment: im pretty sure you have to be server 08r2 or higher functional level..... but I can't find documentation on it.

Comment: It's there in 2008 R2 and the tab states that it requires at least Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a newer version of the Group Policy Management Console. Ideally, install RSAT on your Windows 7 or newer Workstation and manage it remotely.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to run a batch file containing something along the lines of

```
powershell c:\path\to\powershellscript.ps1
```

or

```
powershell \\servername\share\powershellscript.ps1
```

(You might have to enable powershell on the workstations first.)

Comment: while correct, this doesn't answer the question, which is about running PowerShell scripts *natively* in a GPO.

Comment: The question is actually "Why is there no 'powershell' tab in the group policy scripts dialog?"  I don't think "Why is the tab designed the way it is?" is an answerable question suitable for Server Fault.  The implied question is "How do I run a powershell script at start up without a powershell tab in the group policy scripts dialog?"